# How to say "You must let me speak." in German?

Tags: english-to-german, verb

It seems that I have three verbs in my sentence. Are `must` and `let` verbs? `Must` turns to `to have` in its verb form, but `let`?

Comment: `Must` is verb form - isn't it? What else?

Comment: I am downvoting because this Question is barely comprehensible and the Asker has not been back to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

> Du musst mich sprechen lassen.

The verbs don't change, they are the direct translations.

Also read the comments, they may be important.

Comment: Or:
Sie mussen mich sprechen lassen?
Thank you.

Comment: Norman: actually "Sie müssen mich sprechen lassen."

Comment: How do you know the required style? Siezen and Duzen can both be correct, depending on the situation and styling of address.

Comment: @user2553: Without context, we don't.

Comment: Yay! My guess was correct! Thank you, thank you! :D

Comment: I have never in the 46 years of my life heard anyone say "Du musst mich sprechen lassen". The only contexts, where it might make sense, is for an actor to say: "Du musst mich (vor)sprechen lassen." or for someone to tell the warden in a jail: "Du musst mich mit ihm reden lassen." In all other situations something like "Ich möchte jetzt etwas sagen." or "Lass mich auch mal was sagen." would be much more common.

Comment: @what: I hear and use that often enough. Maybe it's a local thing.

Comment: I have to agree with what @what said. Du musst mich sprechen lassen doesn't really sounds genuine to me. We don't have any context but I would say that he actually is looking for "Du musst mich ausreden lassen"

Answer (score 3):

I find this formulation much beter:

> Lass mich ausreden!  Lassen Sie mich ausreden!
>
> Du musst mich ausreden lassen!  Sie müssen mich ausreden lassen!

Comment: Das wäre `you must let me finish speaking`, wäre es nicht?

Comment: "wäre es nicht" ist Denglisch, "nicht wahr" ist Deutsch.

Comment: Ja, aber der Satz auf Englisch unterscheidet die zwei Bedeutungen nicht.

Comment: Wir haben keinen Kontext, aber ich dachte auch zuerst and "ausreden"...

Comment: Going by some of OP's other Questions, his grasp of English seems to be a bit shaky. Maybe OP wanted to ask for German translation of "Let me finish!" In that case, Brian's first choice, "Lass mich (or: Lassen Sie mich) ausreden!" would be very good.

Comment: Eh >< No :( My English being shaky in sense of maybe I lack grammar knowledge. And actually now that I see your "Let me finish", I had "Let me finish my sentence" sort of in mind.